# Broken images in PHP from Dropbox over https

Tags: php, image, firefox, https, dropbox

I have a strange situation with PHP working differently from HTML. I'm not a web programmer, just messing around. In HTML my images appear fine, in PHP the images are broken. And only public images from my Dropbox https server are broken, ones from a http server work.

As an example, here are two files on my localhost, abc.html and def.php. They try to display two images, one pointing to my https image, and another pointing to the Google logo.

abc.html:

```
<img src='https://photos-1.dropbox.com/i/l/EyvpAUN99vGCmWKqw-ywSYXY1L8dPhkloKA5i9I--NM'>
<img src='http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en_uk/images/logo.gif'>
```

def.php:

```
<?php
echo "<img src='https://photos-1.dropbox.com/i/l/EyvpAUN99vGCmWKqw-ywSYXY1L8dPhkloKA5i9I--NM'>";
echo "<img src='http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en_uk/images/logo.gif'>";
exit;
```

Browsing to abc.html shows both images perfectly. Browsing to def.php only shows the Google logo and the other image is broken.

It doesn't work on Firefox however someone told me it works on Opera.

Ideas please :)

---

**Edit**: def.php outputs this:

```
<img src='https://photos-1.dropbox.com/i/l/EyvpAUN99vGCmWKqw-ywSYXY1L8dPhkloKA5i9I--NM'><img src='http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en_uk/images/logo.gif'>
```

Comment: the plain html doesnt work for me, so dont think its a php issue. other images with https src work, so I assume its some combination of that image (or its url) and the server. This is an interesting one!

Comment: i dont thing that there is a problem with the https:// you can delete it and change it with http:// and you get the broken image too. Its a little bit funny, i will search for this error

Comment: What's the output of def.php?

Comment: @David Grant: I added the output to the bottom of the question.

Comment: I tried turning my firewall off but it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend installing [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see what the return response from the server is.  You might find that DropBox is refusing to serve requests for images with referrals from files ending with certain extensions, e.g. .php.

This might explain the duplicate behaviour with the plain HTTP too.

Comment: I installed Firebug, and the command line output for the page gave this error: "NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - https://photos-1.dropbox.com/i/l/EyvpAUN99vGCmWKqw-ywSYXY1L8dPhkloKA5i9I--NM". I don't know how to decipher the response headers to figure it out.

Comment: Perhaps you could supply the headers?

Comment: According to the creator of a Dropbox gallery plugin, "Dropbox don't allow to show photo with HTTP_REFERER different of dropbox.com". This sort of confirms your theory, so you get the points.

Answer (score 0):

This works on my Firefox version 3.6, the image shows perfectly well:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>My WebPage</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

  <img src="https://photos-1.dropbox.com/i/l/EyvpAUN99vGCmWKqw-ywSYXY1L8dPhkloKA5i9I--NM" />

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Is that the source of a PHP generated page? I can get it to work from a normal HTML page just not from a PHP generated one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
echo '<img src="https://photos-1.dropbox.com/i/l/EyvpAUN99vGCmWKqw-ywSYXY1L8dPhkloKA5i9I--NM">';
echo '<img src="http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en_uk/images/logo.gif">';
exit;
```

If that works, it's because html attributes should be bounded by double quotes, not single quotes. Perhaps some browsers forgive that and some do not.

Comment: If browsers are unforgiving of this error, why does the Google logo work?

Answer (score 0):

An obvious observation but does your def.php have the closing php tag?  Your code example does not...

```
<?php
echo '<img src="https://photos-1.dropbox.com/i/l/EyvpAUN99vGCmWKqw-ywSYXY1L8dPhkloKA5i9I--NM">';
echo '<img src="http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en_uk/images/logo.gif">';
exit;
?>
```

Edit:  Saved the above as a html file, and I only see one image in Chrome...  ALSO - Do you have the PHP module installed/associated with your web server?

Comment: The output is still valid, however.

Comment: The PHP has been interpreted - see the output.

Comment: You don't need the closing tag in PHP.  In fact, if you submit something to PEAR, your contribution will be rejected if you include the closing tag, as it's against the PEAR coding standards: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php

Comment: @R. Bemrose.  Didn´t know that you don't need the closing php tag!  Thanks.
@David Grant.  You're right.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'view source' in both and compare the results.